# Add custom properties in a SharePoint list template (.stp)?

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, rest

I am using a custom list template in SharePoint Server (2019). How can I add a custom property (with a default/fixed value) in the manifest.xml file that will be available for all the lists that are created from this template using SharePoints api? For example, I would like to do something like this:

```
/_api/lists/GetByTitle('MyLibrary')/rootfolder/properties?$select=MyCustomProperty
```

Or is there another way to find out which template was used to create my lists?

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to determine the List Template (SPListTemplate) that was used to create a list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35511/how-to-determine-the-list-template-splisttemplate-that-was-used-to-create-a-li)

And: https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/sharepoint-list-templates/

Use Sharepoint Online Management Shell:

```
$extracted = Get-SPOSiteScriptFromList -ListUrl "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/strategy/customer-contacts"

Add-SPOSiteScript -Title "Customer Tracker" -Description "This creates a customer contact list" -Content $extracted

Add-SPOListDesign -Title "Customer tracking" -Description "Tracks key customer data in a list" -SiteScripts "<ID from previous step>" -ListColor Orange -ListIcon BullseyeTarget -Thumbnail "https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/site-thumbnail.png"
```

List templates can’t be updated after you add them, you need to remove the existing template and add the updated version.

Use the `SPList.RootFolder.Properties["vti_listservertemplate"]` property to find out which template was used to create a list.